# Try Catch AssertionError return worng

Tags: java, assert

So I tried to create a simple request login using API, actually there isn't error when user success login and give status code 200 and the assertEqual pass the condition. But when I tried to add try-catch exception it returns failed condition

```
public static void login_OK(){
try {
    RestAssured.baseURI = PropertiesReader.readProperty("apiUrl");
    RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();

    request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.header("Accept", "application/json");

    JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject(); 
    requestBody.put("email","dummy2@mail.com");
    requestBody.put("password","R3st@mu");
    request.body(requestBody.toJSONString());
    System.out.println(requestBody.toJSONString());

    Response response = request.post("/auth/login");

    int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
    String jsonString = response.asString();
    System.out.println(statusCode);
    
        Assert.assertEquals(statusCode,"200");
        token = JsonPath.from(jsonString).get("content");
        System.out.println(token);

    }catch(AssertionError e){
        System.out.println("Failed to login");
    }
}
```

the output is

```
{"password":"R3st@mu","email":"dummy2@mail.com"}
200
Failed to login
```

I don't know why my code return failed message.

Comment: statusCode does not equal to 200, maybe 302?

Comment: here the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: expected [200] but found [200]

Comment: You are comparing an `int` to a `String`. Try using `200` instead of `"200"`.